# How to get first x chars from a string, without cutting off the last word?

Tags: php, string, substr

I have the following string in a variable.

```
Stack Overflow is as frictionless and painless to use as we could make it.
```

I want to fetch first 28 characters from the above line, so normally if I use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) then it will give me `Stack Overflow is as frictio` this output but I want output as:

```
Stack Overflow is as...
```

Is there any pre-made function in PHP to do so, Or please provide me code for this in PHP?

**Edited:**

I want total 28 characters from the string without breaking a word, if it will return me few less characters than 28 without breaking a word, that's fine.

Comment: So you don't really want the first 28 characters but rather the first few words up to length 28. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I want total 28 characters.. without breaking a word, if it will return me few less characters than 28 without breaking a word, that's fine...

Comment: Than make sure that that is clearly specified in the question!

Comment: @Miky D, earlier I thought it will be more clear by example, anyways edited the post.

Comment: Related: [How to add an ellipsis hyperlink after the first space beyond 170 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49422099/2943403) and [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2154220/2943403)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/wordwrap) function, then explode on newline and take the first part:

```
$str = wordwrap($str, 28);
$str = explode("\n", $str);
$str = $str[0] . '...';
```

Comment: I marked this as answer, but its creating problem when I am using `strip_tags` for string. I have a rich text (html tags included) string and I want to `strip_tags` from that string and then get fixed number of characters. But then its returning blank, because I think with `strip_tags($str)` It vanishes all `/n` due to which explode not able to explode the string properly and it returns blanks string. Any solution to this issue?

Comment: Could you use `str_word_count`(http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) to check the contents then iterate to the next `$str[]` element if it returns `0`?

Comment: I marked this as an answer beacuse its seems to be the best and my problem is solved 100% Thanks @Greg

Comment: Is there a similar function for *words* instead of characters?

Answer (score 11):

From [AlfaSky](http://www.alfasky.com/?p=20):

```
function addEllipsis($string, $length, $end='…')
{
    if (strlen($string) > $length)
    {
        $length -= strlen($end);
        $string  = substr($string, 0, $length);
        $string .= $end;
    }

    return $string;
}
```

An alternate, more featureful implementation from [Elliott Brueggeman's blog](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/tag/trim/):

```
/**
 * trims text to a space then adds ellipses if desired
 * @param string $input text to trim
 * @param int $length in characters to trim to
 * @param bool $ellipses if ellipses (...) are to be added
 * @param bool $strip_html if html tags are to be stripped
 * @return string 
 */
function trim_text($input, $length, $ellipses = true, $strip_html = true) {
    //strip tags, if desired
    if ($strip_html) {
        $input = strip_tags($input);
    }

    //no need to trim, already shorter than trim length
    if (strlen($input) <= $length) {
        return $input;
    }

    //find last space within length
    $last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), ' ');
    $trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);

    //add ellipses (...)
    if ($ellipses) {
        $trimmed_text .= '...';
    }

    return $trimmed_text;
}
```

(Google search: "php trim ellipses")

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
$str = "Stack Overflow is as frictionless and painless to use as we could make it.";

$strMax = 28;
$strTrim = ((strlen($str) < $strMax-3) ? $str : substr($str, 0, $strMax-3)."...");

//or this way to trim to full words
$strFull = ((strlen($str) < $strMax-3) ? $str : strrpos(substr($str, 0, $strMax-3),' ')."...");
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest way:

```
<?php 
$title = "this is the title of my website!";
$number_of_characters = 15;
echo substr($title, 0, strrpos(substr($title, 0, $number_of_characters), " "));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest solution I know of...

```
substr($string,0,strrpos(substr($string,0,28),' ')).'...';
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$string='Stack Overflow is as frictionless and painless to use as we could make it.';
$n=28;
$break=strpos(wordwrap($string, $n,'<<||>>'),'<<||>>');
print substr($string,0,($break==0?strlen($string):$break)).(strlen($string)>$n?'...':'');

$string='Stack Overflow';
$n=28;
$break=strpos(wordwrap($string, $n,'<<||>>'),'<<||>>');
print substr($string,0,($break==0?strlen($string):$break)).(strlen($string)>$n?'...':'');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [string tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) to split the string into words much like this:

```
$string = "Stack Overflow is as frictionless and painless to use as we could make it.";
$tokenized_string = strtok($string, " ");
```

Then you can pull out the individual words any way you want.

---

Edit: Greg has a much better and more elegant way of doing what you want. I would go with his wordwrap() solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [wordwrap](http://www.php.net/wordwrap).

```
string wordwrap  ( string $str  [, int $width= 75  [, string $break= "\n"  [, bool $cut= false  ]]] )
```

-

```
function firstNChars($str, $n) {
  return array_shift(explode("\n", wordwrap($str, $n)));
}

echo firstNChars("bla blah long string", 25) . "...";
```

disclaimer: didn't test it.

additionally, if your string contains `\n`s, it might get broken earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
function truncate( $string, $limit, $break=" ", $pad="...") {

 // return with no change if string is shorter than $limit
 if(strlen($string) <= $limit){
    return $string;
 }

 $string = substr($string, 0, $limit);
 if(false !== ($breakpoint = strrpos($string, $break))){
    $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint);
 }
 return $string . $pad;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems can arise if your string has html tags, &nbsp and multiple spaces. Here is what I use that takes care of everything:

```
function LimitText($string,$limit,$remove_html=0){
    if ($remove_html==1){$string=strip_tags($string);}
    $newstring = preg_replace("/(?:\s|&nbsp;)+/"," ",$string, -1); // replace &nbsp with space
    $newstring = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/','/[\t\n]/'),' ',$newstring); // replace duplicate spaces
    if (strlen($newstring)<=$limit) { return $newstring; } // ensure length is more than $limit
    $newstring = substr($newstring,0,strrpos(substr($newstring,0,$limit),' '));
    return $newstring;
}
```

usage:

```
$string = 'My wife is jealous of stackoverflow';
echo LimitText($string,20);
// My wife is jealous
```

usage with html:

```
$string = '<div><p>My wife is jealous of stackoverflow</p></div>';
echo LimitText($string,20,1);
// My wife is jealous
```

Answer (score 0):

This's Working for me Perfect

```
function WordLimt($Keyword,$WordLimit){

    if (strlen($Keyword)<=$WordLimit) { return $Keyword; }
    $Keyword= substr($Keyword,0,strrpos(substr($Keyword,0,$WordLimit),' '));
    return $Keyword;
}

echo WordLimt($MyWords,28);

// OutPut : Stack Overflow is as
```

it will adjust and break on last Space without cut word...

Answer (score -1):

why not try exploding it and getting the first 4 elements of the array?

Answer (score -1):

```
substr("some string", 0, x);
```

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Ya but using this breaks the words sometimes... and I have mentioned in my question that substr is not doing what I want, please read the question again :)

Comment: Scroll down to the advanced version.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#73233