# Limit String Length

Tags: php, string

I'm looking for a way to limit a string in php and add on ... at the end if the string was too long.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->truncate($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L233) or even [`s($str)->truncateSafely($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L246) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Comment: Working example:https://stackoverflow.com/a/66662165/7186739

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You can use something similar to the below:

```
if (strlen($str) > 10)
   $str = substr($str, 0, 7) . '...';
```

Comment: I guess you didn't think he might be skipping his homework reading assignments.

Comment: Sorry no I didn't consider that. What are the rules for homework?

Oh and wait, I just noticed, my code doesn't even work correctly ;)

Comment: It's just a community rule: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: For getting a substring of UTF-8 characters, I highly recommend mb_substr -> `mb_substr($utf8string,0,5,'UTF-8');` You would avoid wrong lenght of the slice this way.

Answer (score 50):

From **php 4.0.6** , there is a function for the exact same thing

function **mb**_**strimwidth** can be used for your requirement

```
<?php
echo mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...");
//Hello W...
?>
```

It does have more options though,here is the documentation for this [mb_strimwidth](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php)

Comment: wordwrap() function can also be usefull: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_wordwrap.asp

Comment: But personally, i prefer to use : $s=preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($s, $START, $LIMIT));

Comment: @CyrilJacquart its better to avoid using regular expressions where ever its not necessary.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `wordwrap()` function then explode on newline and take the first part, if you don't want to split words.

```
$str = 'Stack Overflow is as frictionless and painless to use as we could make it.';
$str = wordwrap($str, 28);
$str = explode("\n", $str);
$str = $str[0] . '...';
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1104329/1060423

If you don't care about splitting words, then simply use the [php substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
echo substr($str, 0, 28) . '...';
```

Answer (score 11):

2nd argument is where to start string and 3rd argument how many characters you need to show

```
$title = "This is for testing string for get limit of string This is for testing string for get limit of string This is for testing string for get limit of string This is for testing string for get limit of string";
    echo substr($title,0,50);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 $string = (strlen($string) > 13) ? substr($string,0,10).'...' : $string;
```

Or as function:

```
function truncate($string, $length, $dots = "...") {
    return (strlen($string) > $length) ? substr($string, 0, $length - strlen($dots)) . $dots : $string;
}
```

It's been a while since I wrote this answer and I don't actually use this code any more. I prefer this function which prevents breaking the string in the middle of a word using the `wordwrap` function:

```
function truncate($string,$length=100,$append="&hellip;") {
$string = trim($string);

  if(strlen($string) > $length) {
    $string = wordwrap($string, $length);
    $string = explode("\n", $string, 2);
    $string = $string[0] . $append;
  }

  return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a little homework with the [php online manual's string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php).
You'll want to use [`strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) in a comparison setting, [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to cut it if you need to, and the concatenation operator with `"..."` or `"&hellip;"`

Answer (score 1):

To truncate a string provided by the maximum limit without breaking a word use this:

```
/**
 * truncate a string provided by the maximum limit without breaking a word
 * @param string $str
 * @param integer $maxlen
 * @return string
 */
public static function truncateStringWords($str, $maxlen): string
{
    if (strlen($str) <= $maxlen) return $str;

    $newstr = substr($str, 0, $maxlen);
    if (substr($newstr, -1, 1) != ' ') $newstr = substr($newstr, 0, strrpos($newstr, " "));

    return $newstr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, there is a string util function for this, and it is implemented this way:

```
public static function limit($value, $limit = 100, $end = '...')
{
    if (mb_strwidth($value, 'UTF-8') <= $limit) {
        return $value;
    }

    return rtrim(mb_strimwidth($value, 0, $limit, '', 'UTF-8')).$end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$res = explode("\n",wordwrap('12345678910', 8, "...\n",true))[0];

// $res will be  : "12345678..."
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

In another way to limit a string in php and add on readmore text or like '...' using below code

```
if (strlen(preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $string)) > 30) { 
    echo substr(preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $string), 0, 35).'&hellip;'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
function truncateString($string, $maxlength, $ellipsis = false){

    if(mb_strlen($string) <= $maxlength){
        return $string;
    }

    if(empty($ellipsis)){
        $ellipsis = '';
    }

    if($ellipsis === true){
        $ellipsis = '…';
    }

    $ellipsis_length = mb_strlen($ellipsis);

    $maxlength = $maxlength - $ellipsis_length;

    $string = trim(mb_substr($string, 0, $maxlength)) . $ellipsis;

    return $string;

}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/968e2fd1e98b60828a12d6dc0b68ec38b3628757

Answer (score 0):

```
function showAHumanDate( $dateString ){
$toRet = '';
$days = date( "d", strtotime( $dateString ) );
$month = date( "F", strtotime( $dateString ) );
$year = date( "Y", strtotime( $dateString ) );

switch( $days ){
    case '01':
    $string = '1st';
    break;
    case '02':
    $string = '2nd';
    break;
    case '03':
    $string = '3rd';
    break;
    case '21':
    $string = '21st';
    break;
    case '22':
    $string = '22nd';
    break;
    case '23':
    $string = '23rd';
    break;
    case '31':
    $string = '31st';
    break;
    default:
    $string = $days.'th';
}

// strip the month to three letters: 
$month = mb_strimwidth( $month, 0, 3, '' );

$toRet = $string.' '.$month.' '.$year;
return $toRet;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

$value = str_limit('This string is really really long.', 7);

// This st...

Comment: That's a Laravel thing

Comment: Even that is removed from Laravel. It's `Str::limit($s);` now