# limiting number of letters for registering a new user name

Tags: php

I have a forum and visitors can register user names with more than 20 letters, how can I deny those visitors to register with a  (long) user names?

the registration form is using PHP language.

thanks,

Comment: Anything from database constraints to a simple `if` statement. This is so open-ended that there is no way to answer it meaningfully.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit String Length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019285/limit-string-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `maxlength` attribute to your HTML form as a first-step measure.

```
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" />
```

On the PHP side, you can use `strlen` to check the length of your passed parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Make a condition.

```
if (strlen($_POST['whatever-username-field']) > 20){
   // not allowed to proceed 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strlen()` function which is supposed to mean *string length* like this:

```
if(strlen($username) > 20) {echo "You can not enter more than 20 characters";}
```

Or in your html form use the max length attribute. like:

```
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="20" />
```

Comment: your condition is wrong...

Comment: FYI, your HTML is not XHTML compliant