# limit php varible output in script

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
  $feature_title = trim($array_item[0]);
                                $feature_value ="";
                                if(isset($array_item[1]))
                                {
                                    $feature_value = trim($array_item[1]);
                                }

                                if($feature_title!="" && $feature_value!="" )
                                {
                                    $t= $this->addProductFeature($product->id,$default_language_id, $feature_title , $feature_value);
                                }
```

Problem is that sometimes the $feature_value is too long. I would like to to limit the output to 200 chars and thought that "trim" would be enough but it is not.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019285/limit-string-length

Comment: try using  the substr(); function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit String Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019285/limit-string-length)

Comment: Depending on how long the text is, it might look better to use CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. Depending on the characters in the string, different strings with the same number of characters will occupy different amounts of space.

Comment: I came up with this code but it does not seem to work 'if(strlen($feature_value) > 255){
                                 $feature_value = substr($feature_value, 250);
                                }'

Comment: `trim` does not limit the amount of content, it just remove whitespaces before and after a string.

Comment: @MammaMia that is why I put it under '$feature_value ="";' But I guess I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I finally changed

```
 $t= $this->addProductFeature($product->id,$default_language_id, $feature_title , $feature_value);
```

to

```
$t= $this->addProductFeature($product->id,$default_language_id, $feature_title , substr($feature_value,0,255));
```

Hope I didn't brake anything. Seems to work though
Thanks everyone