# How can I make sure it checks if there is a minimum of 30 characters in an input?

Tags: php

I would like to check in PHP that if you enter something you need at least 30 characters.

If I run it now I can just keep going if I type nr: 31 for example.

```
if(empty($_POST['vraag'])) { 
    $vraagErr = 'Verplicht!'; 
} else { 
    $vraag = test_input($_POST['vraag']);

    if($_POST['vraag']<"30") { //This is the if instruction 
        $vraagErr = 'U moet meer dan 30 karakters invullen'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit String Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019285/limit-string-length)

Answer (score 1):

Use [strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to check this length:

```
if(strlen($_POST['vraag'])<30) { ...
```

*Note: I'm suggesting you to use trim() as well.*

Comment: @lucasCulhaci, you're welcome, you can accept the answer you've liked

Answer (score 0):

Use [mb_strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) to check it.

```
    if(mb_strlen($_POST['vraag']<"30")){

        // ....
    }
```