# Extract a fixed number of chars from an array, just full words

Tags: php

Hey there, 
I have a custom text inside a variable:

```
$myvar = 'this is my custom text, it is a very long text so be patiente, take care!";
```

I need to display lets say the first 100 chars from $myvar, but i need full words.
For example:
this is my custom text, it is a ver... (i don't want to cut words when i extract)

How can i do this?

Thank you!

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You don't want to cut words, but you want only full words, and you want exactly 100 characters. Huh?

Comment: @Tomalak I'm guessing 100 is a limit.

Comment: 100 is an example, i want it to be flexible, i can choos 70, 90, 100 - thei are limits, ty very much

Comment: So you didn't mean "fixed number of chars", then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are heaps of ways, but try this:

```
$shortVersion = substr($myvar, 0, 100);
if(strlen($myvar)>100 && preg_match('`\w`', $myvar{100}))
    $shortVersion = preg_replace('`\w+$`', '', $shortVersion);
```

That's probably your path of least resistance.

Comment: Another straightforward way is: [How to get first x chars from a string, without cutting off the last word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104306/how-to-get-first-x-chars-from-a-string-without-cutting-off-the-last-word)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of examples of this in the [user comments on substr() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

One of the simpler ones is:

```
function wrapTrunc($str, $len) {
  return substr(($str=wordwrap($myvar,$len,'$$')),0,strpos($str,'$$'));
}
```

A major disadvantage of this `wordwrap`-based approach is you waste time and memory wrapping the whole string, even though you only need to keep the first `$len` chars.

Here's a regex-based solution I just whipped up that I'm a little more comfortable with:

```
<?php
$myvar = 'this is my custom text, it is a very long text so be patiente, take care!';
var_dump(trunc($myvar, 50));
function trunc($str, $len = 50) {
  return preg_replace("/^(.{1,$len}\S)\b.*/", '$1', $str);
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ php test.php
string(49) "this is my custom text, it is a very long text so"
```

Comment: I like this, it's neater than my suggestion, but I don't think it'll work if the original is less than 100 characters to begin with, or if the original string contains `$$`. Also, I assume your `$` is meant to be 100 :-)

Comment: Yep, you're right on both counts.  Also, I think your regex is cleaner than mine.  I'm sure there are some edge cases my regex is wrong for, but it's close.

Comment: Only think I'd change is maybe using `\w` instead of `\S`, depending on whether you want to break on hyphens or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Since we're putting code in, my 2 cents:

```
<?php
function noWordCut($str, $len, $before=true, $add=' ...', $punctuation=array(' ',',','.','!','?',';')){
    if(!isset($str[$len]))return $str;
    if(in_array($str[$len], $punctuation))return substr($str, 0, $len).$add;
    $dir=($before)?-1:1;
    for(;$len+=$dir;)
        if(in_array($str[$len], $punctuation))
            return substr($str, 0, $len).$add;
    return $str;// one big chunk of word?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess what. There is a [built-in](http://php.net/wordwrap) PHP function for that :)

```
print wordwrap($text, 100);
```

Ooops, for cutting of the first line you can use:

```
$first = strtok(wordwrap($text, 100), "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume we have the string variables **$string**, **$start**, and **$limit** we can borrow 3 or 4 functions from PHP to achieve this. They are:

- **script_tags()** PHP function to remove the unnecessary HTML and PHP
  tags (if there are any). This wont be necessary, if there are no HTML or PHP tags.
- **explode()** to split the **$string** into an array
- **array_splice()** to specify the number of words and where it'll start
  from. It'll be controlled by vallues assigned to our **$start** and **$limit** variables.
- and finally, **implode()** to join the array elements into your truncated
  string..

  ```
  function truncateString($string, $start, $limit){
      $stripped_string =strip_tags($string); // if there are HTML or PHP tags
      $string_array =explode(' ',$stripped_string);
      $truncated_array = array_splice($string_array,$start,$limit);
      $truncated_string=implode(' ',$truncated_array);

      return $truncated_string;
  }
  ```

It's that simple..

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a bad example that probably wastes lots of processing time and memory:

```
<?php
    $text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin congue, quam nec tincidunt congue, massa ipsum sodales tellus, in rhoncus sem quam quis ante. Nam condimentum pellentesque libero at blandit.";
    $length = 100;
    $words = explode(' ', $text);
    for ($x=0; $x <= count($words); $x++) {
        $output = implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $x));
        if (strlen($output) >= $length) {
            echo $output . '...';
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Why?** Because I can.