# PHP wont echo previous set of data

Tags: php, sql

for some reason when I try to display all 5 sets of data it only displays 4 and refuses to display the newest added set of data. Could anyone help me figure out why this is happening? I'm selecting everything from the table at the start of the page.

```html
<article class="uk-article">
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($i%1 == 0) {
            echo'<div><div>';
        }
            echo "
                <h2>
                    <a class=uk-link-reset href='projectdetails.php?ID={$row['ID']}' uk-toggle>
                        {$row['title']}
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <p class='uk-article-meta'>Written by {$row['author']}</p>
            ";
        if (strlen($row['info']) > 10) {

            // cut the article
            $infoCut= substr($row['info'], 0, 250);

            //ensure that it ends with a whole word
            $row['info'] = substr($infoCut, 0, strrpos($infoCut, ' ')). "... <a class=uk-link-reset href='projectdetails.php?ID={$row['ID']}' uk-toggle>
                        Read More
                    </a> " ; 
        }
        echo "
            <p> {$row['info']} </p>
        ";
        if($i%1 == 0) {
                echo '</div>
                    </div>'; 
                }
            $i++;
        }
?>
</article>
```

Comment: Check if strlen($row['info']) condition satisfy the newly added data

Comment: What is the benefit to using the double `<div>`?  What is your actual intended logic while using `if($i%1 == 0) {`?  ...that little baby is gonna be `true` every time.  Is `uk-toggle` meant to be a stand alone attribute, or is that supposed to be in the class declaration?

Comment: try to print the result with print_r(), make sure you get the right result first

Comment: Don't go away newcomer, your question is **Offtopic: Why isn't my code working**.  Please update your question.

Comment: Have you done a View Source to check if the data is there but not visible because of an error in the HTML?

Comment: Are you, by chance, calling an earlier `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` that you aren't telling us about?  Some times newer developers use that one-off call to check that the query was successful and don't realize that it chews up the first row data.  I'll post an answer that has several pieces of advice / refinements for you to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "fetchless" approach to iterate your result set and use the row indexes as your counter.  I assume that you want to group your results in pairs (otherwise, I can't imagine what your are trying to do with the remainder generated from dividing by 1).

Here's a previous post where I show how to truncate a string at a certain point and add an ellipsis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422362/2943403

When finished iterating, it is important to close any potential open containers, this is why my code checks for an even `$i` value.

```
$query="SELECT `ID`, `title`, `author`, `info` FROM `your_table`";
if (!$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbname")) {
    echo "Database Connection Error";
} elseif (!$result = $conn->query($query)) {
    echo "Syntax Error";
} else {
    echo "<article class='uk-article'>";
    foreach ($result as $i => $row) {  // fetchless result set iteration
        if (!($i & 1)) { // not odd
            if ($i) { // not zero
                echo "</div>"; // close the open container
            }
            echo "<div style='border:solid 1px black'>"; // create new container for potential pair
        }
        echo "<h2><a class='uk-link-reset' href='projectdetails.php?ID={$row['ID']}' uk-toggle>{$row['title']}</a></h2>";
        echo "<p class='uk-article-meta'>Written by {$row['author']}</p>";
        $ellipsis = "...<a class=uk-link-reset href='projectdetails.php?ID={$row['ID']}' uk-toggle>Read More</a>";
        echo "<p>" , preg_replace('/.{250}\S*\s\K.+/s', $ellipsis, $row['info']) , "</p>";  // only use ellipsis when qualified/needed
    }
    if (!empty($i) && !($i & 1)) {  // $i is declared and is even (ensure valid DOM is generated)
        echo "</div>"; // create new container for potential pair
    }
    echo "</article>";
}
```