# Equally divide address into 2 parts after comma in PHP

Tags: php

I am facing a situation in which I need to divide the `address` equally into 2 parts i.e `address1` and `address2` if address is longer than 80 characters.

I able to add below condition with `strlen` to find if address is greater than 80 characters but facing issue in dividing the address equally after comma when address is longer then 80 characters.

My code is as below :-

```
// Sample Address
$address = "House No. 1234-ABC, Second Floor, XYZ Building, ABC Mall Road, Street Number 1234, ABC Area";

$address_length = strlen($address);

if(address_length > 80){
    // Split Long Address Code
    $address_equal_length = $address_length/2;
    $address1 = substr($address,0,$address_equal_length);
    $address2 = substr($address,$address_equal_length,$address_length); 
}
```

Unfortunately, above code will not check comma and split the address like below :-

```
$address1 = "House No. 1234-ABC, Second Floor, XYZ Buildin";
$address2 = "g, ABC Mall Road, Street Number 1234, ABC Area";
```

You can see it cuts `Building` word and shows it as `Buildin` in the end of `$address1` and `g` in the beginning of `$address2`

I want the `$address` to be divided like below :-

```
$address1 = "House No. 1234-ABC, Second Floor, XYZ Building";
$address2 = "ABC Mall Road, Street Number 1234, ABC Area";
```

Hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if you want to do this youll probably have to explode the string on commas (like the split function in other languages) nad go through it with a for loop adding them to a string chrecking the length each time

Comment: Please explain with code

Comment: The most easy way would be to use explode() use count() to get the item count then you know how to divide the items.. the problem is still are the items always even numbers so you can indeed equally divide

Comment: Are they always separaterd by 2 comma's?

Comment: Yes I want to separate them with the middle one who is located at the middle of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start could be :

```
// Sample Address
$address = "House No. 1234-ABC, Second Floor, XYZ Building, ABC Mall Road, Street Number 1234, ABC Area";

$address_length = strlen($address);

if($address_length > 80){
    // Split Long Address Code
    $address_equal_length = $address_length/2;
    $commaIndex = strrpos(substr($address,0,$address_equal_length),',');
    $address1 = substr($address, 0,$commaIndex);
    $address2 = substr($address,$commaIndex + 1); 
}
```

You'll need to test if $commaIndex exists to be sure that substr doesn't fail.

**Edit**

An optimized solution, which looks for the closest comma at the center of the string :

```
<?php

// Sample Address
$address = "House No. 1234-ABC, Second Floor, XYZ Building, ABC Mall Road, Street Number 1234, ABC Area";

$address_length = strlen($address);

if($address_length > 80){
    // We gonna look for the comma which is the more close to the center of the string
    $address_equal_length = $address_length/2;
    $comma_index_before = strrpos(substr($address, 0, $address_equal_length), ',');
    $comma_index_after = strpos($address, ',', $address_equal_length);
    if ($comma_index_before === false) {
        $comma_index_before = 0;
    }
    if ($comma_index_after === false) {
        $comma_index_after = $address_length;
    }
    $comma_index = $address_equal_length - $comma_index_before <= $comma_index_after - $address_equal_length ? $comma_index_before : $comma_index_after;

    $address1 = substr($address, 0, $comma_index);
    $address2 = substr($address, $comma_index + 1); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A dynamic regular expression is **the most direct/suitable tool for this task**.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/baiAi))

```
$address = "House No. 1234-ABC, Second Floor, XYZ Building, ABC Mall Road, Street Number 1234, ABC Area";
$length = strlen($address);  // 91
if ($length > 80) {
    $middle = floor(strlen($address) / 2);  // 45
    [$address1, $address2] = preg_split("~.{{$middle}}[^,]*\K, ?~", $address, 2);
}
```

In my demo, the output from:

```
var_export($address1);
echo "\n";
var_export($address2);
```

is:

```
'House No. 1234-ABC, Second Floor, XYZ Building'
'ABC Mall Road, Street Number 1234, ABC Area'
```

I am using `var_export()` to present the values to prove that this solution includes whitespace trimming at the point of the split.

The pattern breakdown is:

`.{{$middle}}` evaluates as `.{45}` meaning match 45 occurrences of any character
`[^,]*` match zero or more occurrences of non-comma characters
`\K` restart the fullstring match, aka forget the previously matched characters
`, ?` match the comma to split on and optionally the space that follows it

I am writing a hard limit on the `preg_split()` of `2` just be explicit/safe.

I have previously recommended this type of technique when presenting a well-placed ellipsis (read more): [How to add an ellipsis hyperlink after the first space beyond 170 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422362/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

If the addresses are always divided by 2 comma's, you might use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and for example [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to get a number of items. Then reassemble the parts using [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

This will also work for more than 2 addresses.

```
$address = "House No. 1234-ABC, Second Floor, XYZ Building, ABC Mall Road, Street Number 1234, ABC Area";
$address_length = strlen($address);

if ($address_length > 80) {
    $parts = explode(',', $address);
    list($address1, $address2) = array_map(function($x) {
        return trim(implode(',', $x));
    }, array_chunk($parts, 3));
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/MY1OA)

Answer (score 0):

this would be my idea
first you put all the comma parts in an array and then iterate through them to see if they added to the previous length exceed 80 in whihc case you go to the next line

```
   $addressParts=explode(",",$address);
   $endString="";
   $currentLine="";
   foreach($addressParts as $addressPart){
       if(str_len($currentLine.$addressPart)>80){
           $endString=$endString.","$currentLine."<br>";
           $currentLine=$addressPart;
       }else{
           if($currentLine != ""){
              $currentLine=$currentLine.", ".$addressPart;
           }else{
              $currentLine=$currentLine.$addressPart;
            }
       }
   }
   $endString=$endString.$currentLine;

   echo $endString;
```

Comment: Internal server error comes to me.. Have you tried the code at your end? I want 2 strings at end but you are returning one.

Comment: oh you probably want them to show in html right then we need br line breaks (also I keep forgetting the semicolons :/)

Comment: or if you still want to work with them they can be out into an array