# Truncating a slug to maximum length by removing delimited words from the middle of string

Tags: php, regex, explode, slug, truncation

I am trying to ensure that a slug formatted string is within the total character limit by removing words from the middle of the string if warranted.

Sample slug:

`'/job/hello-this-is-my-job-posting-for-a-daycare-im-looking-for-in-91770-rosemead-california-12345'`

The string will always start with `/job/` and end with `in-zipcode-city-state-job_id`. However, there is a 150 character limit to the slug and I am looking to truncate words before the zipcode one at a time so this character limit is not exceeded. I know I have to use regex/explode, but how can I do this? I tried the following but my matches array seems to have too many elements.

```
$pattern = '/-in-\d{5}-(.*)-(.*)-(\d*)/';
$string = '/job/hello-this-is-my-job-posting-for-a-daycare-im-looking-for-in-91770-rosemead-california-12345';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);

// Array
(
    [0] => -in-91770-rosemead-california-12345
    [1] => rosemead
    [2] => california
    [3] => 12345
)
```

Why is `rosemead`, `california`, `12345` considered matches? Shouldn't there only be the first element?

How do I ensure that the complete slug will be a maximum of 150 characters long, with the trailing part (location) included in its entirety, and the leading part (job name) truncated if necessary?

Comment: By default, you get an entry in the `$matches` array for every bracketed expression

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I was only expecting the first element to show up in the array.

Comment: From the manual: 'If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.'

Comment: If you don't want to see those elements in the `$matches` array, then you get specify that those parenthesized subpatterns should be non-capturing by adding `?:` after the open bracket, ie `$pattern = '/-in-\d{5}-(?:.*)-(?:.*)-(?:\d*)/'`

Comment: @bobblebubble that's neat.  Might need to adapt just a little to enforce the '/job/' prefix at the beginning though

Comment: @RobEyre It did break words, was not aware of that at first :) [Here is an **updated regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pYDQwc/6) but no idea if this would work as desired taking longer words into account, it's closed alraedy anyways...

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate of something that addresses only a small part of the _actual question_. Meanwhile I was writing up an answer. Here goes the code, then: https://3v4l.org/Kqh3o ... Note that it's wrapped in a function with the default max length at 150, however I call it with a shorter length because your sample string is 97 characters. I'll post the code here as an answer if this question is reopened.

Comment: I assume this is what you are actually asking for: **How do I ensure that the complete slug will be a maximum 150 characters long, with the trailing part (location) included in its entirety, and the leading part (job name) truncated if necessary?** I've taken the liberty to add that to the end of your question to focus on your actual need.

Comment: @David this question would be more clear if you gave two or three unique (and tricky) sample slugs and your exact desired result for each input slug.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to add an ellipsis hyperlink after the first space beyond 170 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49422099/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using `explode()` and iterating, just with some standard string manipulation:

```
$pattern = '/-in-\d{5}-.*-.*-\d*/';
$string = '/job/hello-this-is-my-job-posting-for-a-daycare-im-looking-for-in-91770-rosemead-california-12345';
$matches = [];

if (!preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
    // mismatched string - error handling here
}

$totalLength = 150;
$maxPrefixLength = $totalLength - strlen($matches[0]);
if ($maxPrefixLength < strlen('/job/')) {
    // no prefix words possible at all - error handling here
}
$prefixLength = max(strlen('/job/'), strrpos(substr($string, 0, $maxPrefixLength), '-'));
$slug = substr($string, 0, $prefixLength) . $matches[0];
```

Comment: The non capture groups in the pattern have no purpose, you can omit them `-in-\d{5}-.*-.*-\d*`

Comment: Yes, easier to take a maximum substring cut off at the last delimiter that fits, than iterate and keep checking the prefix length. Who do you have `$prefixLength = max(` the `max` there though, you only have a single value from `strlen`? That line seems a bit garbled up overall, as `strlen` doesn't take multiple arguments. It seems that the inner expression `strrpos(...)` would suffice.

Comment: @MarkusAO Yep, my mistake - missed a closing bracket.  The purpose of that expression is to find the position of the last '-' character within bounds, but if no dash character is found at all to at least use the length of the '/job/' prefix.  Admittedly I could have split this out into separate steps.

Comment: @Thefourthbird good suggestion - removed from answer

Comment: Then, assume slug `/job/foobardodododo`. What would that line give as the max? (`strrpos` would return `false`.) And then, would we want to use `/job/`, or the slug without delimiters, that starts with `/job/` anyway? Also, you're already checking for `strlen('/job/')` in an earlier conditional.

Comment: The length of the string '/job/' is 5.  In your example ('/job/foobardododo'), the `max(5, false)` would give `5`, meaning that the value used in the slug expression on the next line would be `'/job/' . $matches[0]`.  The OP specified that the slug must start with '/job/'.

Comment: @RobEyre then you would just use `/job/-in-91770-rosemead-california-12345` instead of `/job/foobardododo-in-91770-rosemead-california-12345` because no delimiter was found?

Comment: Indeed, I believe that's the logical conclusion of applying the rules given by the OP (stay within the overall slug length, end with the suffix that matches the regex pattern, start with '/job/', whole words only).

Answer (score 1):

Trimming the leading part of a URL slug to a specified length can be accomplished in a number of ways, some more complicated than others. Here's a flexible utility function with informative comments. We use a regex that extracts the leading part (job name) and the trailing part (location) as the starting point. Then, the maximum allowed length for the job name is counted based on total allowed length, minus location slug length. See the comments for more insight.

```
function trim_slug(string $slug, int $maxlen = 150): string
{
    // check if trimming is required:
    if(strlen($slug) <= $maxlen) {
        return $slug; 
    }
    
    $pattern = '/^(?<job>.+)(?<loc>-in-\d{5}-.*-.*-\d*)$/';
    // $match will have 'job' and 'loc' named keys with the matched values
    preg_match($pattern, $slug, $match);
    
    // raw cut of job name to maximum length:
    $max_job_chars = $maxlen - strlen($match['loc']);
    $job_name = substr($match['job'], 0, $max_job_chars);
    
    // tidy up to last delimiter, if exists, instead of mincing words:
    if($last_delim = strrpos($job_name, '-')) {
        $job_name = substr($match['job'], 0, $last_delim);      
    }
    
    return $job_name . $match['loc'];
}

$string = '/job/hello-this-is-my-job-posting-for-a-daycare-im-looking-for-in-91770-rosemead-california-12345';

echo trim_slug($string, 80);
// result: /job/hello-this-is-my-job-posting-for-a-in-91770-rosemead-california-12345
```

In the usage sample, max length is 80, since your sample string is only 97 chars, and as such would return from the function as-is with the default 150 characters limit. [Demo at 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Kqh3o).

Note that this answer uses PHP standard string functions that are not multibyte-aware. If you expect multibyte content, you should use the corresponding [multibyte string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) to avoid mangled data. (Whether you want multibyte chars in a URL slug to begin with, and what are the best ways of handling that, is the topic for another question.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the input slug into its 3 crucial components,
2. Caluculate the number of characters permitted in the middle portion by subtracting the first and third lengths from the total allowance,
3. Truncate the middle portion (cleanly) by finding the latest occurring hyphen before reaching the character limit, then remove the remaining expendable substring.

This leaves you with a string optimized for greatest length without damaging whole words in the slug.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/55GRn))

```
$slug = '/job/hello-this-is-my-job-posting-for-a-daycare-im-looking-for-in-91770-rosemead-california-12345';

$slugLimit = 70;

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~^(/job/)((?:[^-]*-)*)(in-\d{5}-[^-]*-[^-]*-\d*)$~u',
         fn($m) => implode([
             $m[1],
             preg_replace(
                 '~^.{0,' . ($slugLimit - mb_strlen($m[1] . $m[3]) - 1) . '}-\K.*~u',
                 '',
                 $m[2]
             ),
             $m[3]
         ]),
         $slug
     );
```

Output slug's total length 68 characters:

`/job/hello-this-is-my-job-posting-in-91770-rosemead-california-12345`

---

Or combine the first and second components for simpler processing: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gmtor))

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~^((?:[^-]*-)*)(in-\d{5}-[^-]*-[^-]*-\d*)$~u',
         fn($m) => implode([
             preg_replace(
                 '~^.{0,' . ($slugLimit - mb_strlen($m[2]) - 1) . '}-\K.*~u',
                 '',
                 $m[1]
             ),
             $m[2]
         ]),
         $slug
     );
```

---

Finally, the most compact version that I can think of uses a capture group inside of a lookahead so that the full string match is replaced in the callback. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/EfthD)

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~^(?:[^-]*-)*(?=(in-\d{5}-[^-]*-[^-]*-\d*)$)~u',
         fn($m) => preg_replace(
             '~^.{0,' . ($slugLimit - mb_strlen($m[1]) - 1) . '}-\K.*~u',
             '',
             $m[0]
         ),
         $slug
     );
```

---

If you check `mb_strlen()` of the new slug and it is still over the limit, then you should throw an exception or inform the user of the violation.